# How to close the room which you own

Tags: support, chat

I eventually opened a chat room in the wrong way and now I would like to close it. I've tried to find a procedure to do it but I wasn't successful. Could you help me?

The room is here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1026/discussion-between

Comment: It might be helpful if you included a link to the chat room you opened "in the wrong way". In case you can't close it yourself (I don't know if this is the case) a moderator could just go and close it without further ado.

Comment: @Theo: thank you for the useful comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the room, only moderators should now be able to find it. I'm not sure if a room owner can do that (I think so, but I'm not sure). If you click on "room" on the right there should be an option "delete this room", if you have the rights to do that.

From [this meta question on automatic freezing and deleting of chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65098/should-chat-rooms-with-no-activity-in-x-days-weeks-months-be-removed)

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person
>   actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if
>   it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users. Rooms not worth
>   retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth
>   retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms
>   do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the
>   default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

So the room would have been automatically deleted after 7 days if nobody writes in it.

Comment: thank you. Are you a moderator?

Comment: @Gortaur on a different SE site, not on Math. But all SE 2.0 site moderators are moderators on chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: I understand. thank's again for the help.

Comment: "Inactive chat rooms are frozen and deleted after a few days automatically if nobody writes in them." - I thought as much; now, with that in mind, along with the pestering of the software for extensive comment exchanges to be moved to a chatroom, I suppose these chatroom exchanges will also eventually be deleted?

Comment: @J.M. I added the exact criteria for auto-deletion, only rooms with less than 15 messages are deleted, all others are just frozen and still can be accessed.

Comment: Thanks. $\text{}$